# TypeInitializationException when setting ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback with tracing off

Tags: c#, .net, system.net, system.net.sockets, system.net.websockets

I'm getting an unhandled `TypeInitializationException` exception when I try to set

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => true;
```

The exception happens when I've got the following (taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) in my app.config. The only difference from the config below and that on MSDN is that I've set logging for `System.Net`, `System.Net.Cache`, `System.Net.Sockets` and `System.Net.WebSockets` to `Off`. I only see the issue when all four are off.

Is there something wrong with this configuration or am I missing something else?

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Cache">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Http">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net "/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
      <listeners>
        <add name="System.Net"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Off"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Off"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Off"/>
    <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Off"/>
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="System.Net"
         type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="network.log"
    />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Here's the exception's stack track

```
at System.Net.ServicePointManager.get_ServerCertificateValidationCallback()
at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Eoin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\test\test\Program.cs:line 12
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

There's an inner exception, also of type TypeInitializationException, and the call stack contains only `at System.Net.ServicePointManager..cctor()` and the message is "The type initializer for 'System.Net.ComNetOS' threw an exception.".

This has a final inner exception of type `ConfigurationErrorsException`. The message is "Listener 'System.Net ' does not exist in the sharedListeners section." and the stack trace is

```
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject()
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
at System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
at System.Net.Logging.get_On()
at System.Net.ComNetOS..cctor()
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space in the name of the listener for System.Net.Http.

```
<source name="System.Net.Http">
  <listeners>
    <add name="System.Net "/>
  </listeners>
</source>
```

This will try to find a listener named `"System.Net "` but of course you only have one named `"System.Net"`. Just remove the space and you're golden.